# android: notify the user from service

Tags: android, service

I have to display notification to the user from service always running in background.

I read that we have to use status bar notification to achieve this. But in the status bar icon is very small and user might miss it. I want to notify user similar to "new call notification" or "new message notification"

Please help me how can I construct such notifications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'new message notification' uses the same notification api you are talking about it just displays the message in the status bar.  A new call is an `Activity`. You can start an activity from you service like this

```
startActivity(this, MyActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a notification, use

```
            final Notification notification = new Notification(
                    icon, 
                    "New Message Notification", // <-------
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Consider using the buzzbox sdk for running background tasks and creating notifications. Have a look at http://hub.buzzbox.com   -   open source apps are available as examples.